# Make youtube video fullscreen using iframe and javascript API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have an embedded youtube video with hidden controls:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="400" height="225"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dMH0bHeiRNg?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0
&loop=1&hd=1&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I can control it with the youtube Javascript API.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
});
}
```

Things like `player.playVideo()` and so on work perfectly. Now I am looking for a way to make the video play in fullscreen mode with a Javascript call but I couldn't find any method in the API.

**Is it even possible (without the controls) and if so - how?**

Comment: AFAIK the "true" full-screen is made with Flash (or that _sort of things_)...

Comment: @Adriano Flash is not necessary, a Fullscreen API does already exists, and is implemented by all modern browsers except for IE(10): http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

Comment: @RobW nice, I didn't know it. So sad it's almost impossible to use it if it's not supported by IE (even 10)...:(

Comment: @Adriano That's not necessarily a problem. Use the HTML5 API when available, and use a fallback (such as Flash) when necessary.

Comment: @RobW Right, I get frustrated too easily :)

Answer (score 9):

This worked perfect in my case. You can find more details on this link: [demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/bfred-it/pen/GgOvLM)

```
var player, iframe;
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

// init player
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '200',
    width: '300',
    videoId: 'dQw4w9WgXcQ',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

// when ready, wait for clicks
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  var player = event.target;
  iframe = $('#player');
  setupListener(); 
}

function setupListener (){
$('button').addEventListener('click', playFullscreen);
}

function playFullscreen (){
  player.playVideo();//won't work on mobile

  var requestFullScreen = iframe.requestFullScreen || iframe.mozRequestFullScreen || iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen;
  if (requestFullScreen) {
    requestFullScreen.bind(iframe)();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think [`.requestFullscreen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen) and `.webkitRequestFullscreen` each have a lower case **s**. Moz is the [only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30044770/673991) three-hump camel.

Comment: Note that for iPhone there's no `.webkitRequestFullscreen` and instead there is a `.webkitEnterFullscreen` method that works only on `<video>` elements and only in response to user action, so it won't work on `iframe` and in response to `'onReady'` event,

Answer (score 6):

You can use html5 fullscreen api:

```
node.requestFullScreen();
document.cancelFullScreen();
document.fullScreen; // bool
```

But note that:

- this usually requires vendor specific prefix like `mozRequestFullScreen()` or `webkitRequestFullScreen`
- `requestFullScreen` has to be called on user events (like onclick)
- in firefox the fullscreen will be black until "Allow" is clicked by user

Comment: PSA: note the capital `S` in `requestFullScreen`, afaik it's deprecated (but possibly still in firefox) and should have a small `s`; `requestFullscreen`.

This took me a while to figure out

Comment: Please update the answer. It is outdated and caused me some issues - it is now called `exitFullscreen()` and it returns a promise [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/exitFullscreen) and `fullscreen` property is deprecated in favor of `fullscreenElement`

Answer (score 5):

I've added code to do fullscreen (**real full screen, not full window**) to my answer on [Auto-Full Screen for a Youtube embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615380/auto-full-screen-for-a-youtube-embed).

YouTube don't expose fullscreen in their API, but you can call the native browser requestFullScreen() function from the playerStateChange() event from the YouTube API or make your own custom play button like I have.

Comment: I'm using the native browser requestFullScreen() function, but then the full screen button on youtube remains the same, meaning that it is expecting to fullsize the screen when you click . Any ideas about how to update the button  from fullsize to close fullsize?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API reference for the `iframe` player, I don't think it's possible to set it to fullscreen (with the `iframe` API alone)- `ctrl f` didn't find fullscreen, so either it's a secret method hidden inside the API or it doesn't exist. However, as you probably know, you can set the size of the player `player.setSize(width:Number, height:Number):Object`, then make  the [window fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at this similar question. It looks as though this might work for you (using the javascript fullscreen api rather than the Youtube API):

[Full Screen Option in Chromeless player using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120704/full-screen-option-in-chromeless-player-using-javascript)

Answer (score -5):

You can try setting the iframe dimension to the window dimension through javascript.

Something like this (using jQuery):

```
$('ytplayer').attr('width', $(window).width());
$('ytplayer').attr('height', $(window).height());
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I think the poster means truly full screen, ie larger than the window.