# JavaScript Element.requestFullscreen() is undefined

Tags: javascript

How do I use the code if `element.requestFullscreen()` is undefined?

```
if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
```

Comment: sorry what is the question?

Comment: are you asking about unsupported browsers

Comment: for cross browser support see - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Comment: i have tried in chrome and firefox too..

Comment: if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) { 
  element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
   } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  element.mozRequestFullScreen();
   } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
   } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
  element.msRequestFullscreen();
   } - I am getting undefined for all browsers.. Can anyone Help me

Comment: Is `element` defined?

Comment: Yea you gotta show more code, where did you define `element`

Answer (score 14):

If `requestFullscreen` returns `undefined`, it means that you cannot request fullscreen because that function doesn't exist. Every browser other than IE10 and below supports it but you need to use the right vendor prefix as you commented. A good way you can do that is by doing

```
var requestFullScreen = elem.requestFullscreen || elem.msRequestFullscreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullscreen;
```

I think your issue is you spelled some of the functions wrong. it's confusing because Mozilla uses .mozRequestFull**S**creen whereas the others use requestFull**s**creen. The capital S can be annoying.

where `elem` is the `video` element from the DOM. You can then do `requestFullScreen.call(elem)` and it will initiate fullscreen.

And as @ArunPJohny commented, definitely take a look at that [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode).

Comment: 'var requestFullScreen = elem.requestFullscreen || elem.msRequestFullscreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullscreen;
 var isFullScreenAvailable = document.mozFullScreenEnabled;
 alert(isFullScreenAvailable);' i am getting the alert as **true**.. but not the fullscreen..

Comment: Did you do `requestFullScreen.call(elem)`?

Comment: I was wondering what's wrong with FF, and the capitalization was indeed  the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why the prefixed version is now deprecated in Firefox, but the unprefixed version was not available. The unprefixed version has lowercase "s".