# Youtube player api fullscreen option is not available in mobile android app

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Currently I am working on Youtube videos,

I am facing a issue.

One weird thing I observed that the fullscreen option is not available for mobile app. However it is present in browser of mobile (chrome).

I researched a lot on web but didn't find the answer

Please help me, I want that fullscreen functionality

```
var player = new YT.Player(strId, {
    "height": '200',
    "width": '100%',
    "videoId": 'Hmvz_lKyh',
    "events": {
        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
     },
     "allowfullscreen": true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any answer on this,
So I finally end up with this solution

I have added a button with class "full-screen"

```
var isFullScreenMode = false;

$(".full-screen").on("click", function() {
    if (isFullScreenMode) {
        $(".video-player").height(200);
        isFullScreenMode = false;
    } else {
        $(".video-player").height($(window).height());
        isFullScreenMode = true;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this on an Android app like you mentioned, [.setFullscreen(true)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#setFullscreen(boolean)). You can find a sample implementation in this [blog post](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/06/force-youtube-android-player-to-run-in.html)

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true);
   }});
}
```

If you're doing this for JS or HTML5 for web, check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114884/make-youtube-video-fullscreen-using-iframe-and-javascript-api) for various ways to implement fullscreen.