# allowfullscreen is not working on frameset

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have an old service working on frameset-frame (I know it's deprecated but I have no choice) and users can add youtube iframe tags.
but from some point the fullscreen action is not working anymore(it used to work).
There's allowfullscreen attribute added already.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ea9pOiwzd0c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I tried allowfullscreen on frameset and frame tag also.
I have tried like

```
allowfullscreen
allowfullscreen="true"
allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen"
msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen"
oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen"
webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen"
```

... everything I can find on web but nothing worked for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114884/make-youtube-video-fullscreen-using-iframe-and-javascript-api

Comment: @noogui thx for the answer. unfortunately, the link is not about my question :( although mine is not only about fullscreen but also frameset(old, deprecated tag). I don't think youtube cares about it. No blame since it's deprecated but please take a look at this. it dosen't look that hard to add the option.

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```html
allowfullscreen=true
```