# Programmatically set (Angular) Youtube player full screen

Tags: angular, angular-material, capacitor

youtube-player.html:

```html
<div [ngClass]="{ isPlaying: isPlaying }" #youtubePlayer>
  <youtube-player
    [playerVars]="{ playsinline: 0 }"
    [width]="playerWidth"
    [height]="playerHeight"
    videoId="uDph9wSeWvY"
    (stateChange)="playerStateChanged($event)">
  </youtube-player>
</div>
```

youtube-player.component.ts

```js
import { AfterViewChecked, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { YouTubePlayerModule } from '@angular/youtube-player';
import { StatusBar } from '@capacitor/status-bar';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-youtube-player',
  imports: [CommonModule, YouTubePlayerModule],
  templateUrl: './youtube-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./youtube-player.component.scss'],
})
export class YoutubePlayerComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  @ViewChild('youtubePlayer') private youtubePlayer!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  public isPlaying = false;

  public playerWidth?: number;
  public playerHeight?: number;

  public ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.playerWidth = this.youtubePlayer.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.playerHeight = this.youtubePlayer.nativeElement.offsetWidth * 0.6;
  }

  public playerStateChanged(event: YT.OnStateChangeEvent): void {
    this.isPlaying = event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING;

    if (this.isPlaying) {
      window.screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
      StatusBar.hide();
    } else {
      window.screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
      StatusBar.show();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to set my youtube player to fullscreen when the video is started. But I cannot find anything on how to do that in the docs https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference  https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters The closes thing seems to be `playsinline` but that's only for iOS. Does anyone have a suggestion how to set the Youtube player to fullscreen when playing? I'm also using Capacitor if there's a plugin that does that.

Comment: Real fullscreen is unfortunately not possible with the YT.Player iframe api. But the iframe that was created carries the same id as was used on the div element. So you can just call `(<HTMLIframeElement>youtubePlayer?.nativeElement.querySelector("iframe")).requestFullscreen()` [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36129309/8941307). But as I mentioned, it's not "really" fullscreen