# On Play: Make Youtube Video Full Screen

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-javascript-api

Using the Youtube Javascript API; **is there a way to make the video play full screen when the 'Play' button is clicked?**

I am aware of a way to make the [video container full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120704/full-screen-option-in-chromeless-player-using-javascript) but this only works for the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome.

*If there isn't any way to do this through the Youtube Javascript API, do you know of a Cross Browser way I could make the youtube video full screen when play is clicked?*

This is how you make a video full screen when play is clicked for the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome browsers:

```
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            var player = document.getElementById("MSJbUEj7U7M");
            if (event.data != YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING && event.data != YT.PlayerState.CUED && event.data != YT.PlayerState.PLAYING)
                return -1;

            if (player.requestFullScreen) {
              console.log("1()");
              player.requestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (player.mozRequestFullScreen) {
              console.log("2()");
              player.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (player.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
              console.log("3()");
              player.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }
        }

        function loadYouTubeVideo(uid) {
            setTimeout( function() {
                        var id         = uid;
                        var instPlayer = new YT.Player(id, {
                            height: '480',
                            width: '853',
                            enablejsapi: 1,
                            suggestedQuality: 'highres',
                            videoId: uid,
                            events: {
                                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                            }
                        });
                }, 500);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't do this unless the user clicks full screen.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube-api-gdata/Tyv3vTw0RQk/449KahYVNFYJ

Comment: I you like to the embed video url it will automatically open the video  the full width and height of the browser window. e.g. -> "http://www.youtube.com/embed/om8invGWkeo"